# How do I generate 2d array with distinct number between row and column?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, distinct, sudoku

```
    void generateSudoku(int sudoku[][C])
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
                    {
                        sudoku[i][j] = generateRandNum(); //generate random number for all 2d array
                        while (sudoku[1][0] == sudoku[0][0] || sudoku[2][0] == sudoku[1][0] || sudoku[2][0] == sudoku[0][0]
                            || sudoku[3][0] == sudoku[2][0] || sudoku[3][0] == sudoku[1][0] || sudoku[3][0] == sudoku[0][0])
                            sudoku[i][j] = generateRandNum();
                        while (   sudoku[i][1] == sudoku[i][0] || sudoku[1][1] == sudoku[0][1] || sudoku[2][1] == sudoku[1][1]
                               || sudoku[2][1] == sudoku[0][1] || sudoku[3][1] == sudoku[2][1] || sudoku[3][1] == sudoku[1][1]
                               || sudoku[3][1] == sudoku[0][1]) //index 1 to index 0
                            sudoku[i][j] = generateRandNum();
                        while ( (sudoku[i][2] == sudoku[i][0]) || (sudoku[i][2] == sudoku[i][1]) || sudoku[1][2] == sudoku[0][2]
                               || sudoku[2][2] == sudoku[1][2] || sudoku[2][2] == sudoku[0][2] || sudoku[3][2] == sudoku[2][2]
                               || sudoku[3][2] == sudoku[1][2] || sudoku[3][2] == sudoku[0][2])
                            sudoku[i][j] = generateRandNum();
                        while ( (sudoku[i][3] == sudoku[i][0]) || (sudoku[i][3] == sudoku[i][1]) || (sudoku[i][3] == sudoku[i][2])) //index 3 to index 2,1,0
                            sudoku[i][j] = generateRandNum();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Is there more efficient and easy way to generate 2d array with random numbers that is distinct with each column and row like a sudoku? The code works, but execution time is too long, probably caused by so many loops. Also I'm a beginner (first year cs students) so this is the only way I can think of to make it distinct (yeah i know its stupid and inefficient and wrong), as I don't know how to do complex algorithm.

EDIT: generateRandNum:

```
int generateRandNum()
{
    int randNum;
    randNum = (rand() % 4)+1;
    return randNum;
}
```

Comment: could you post body of generateRandNum?

Comment: posted in main post

Comment: for loop in genRandNum is waste of time, why do you have it there? the function returns only one number and not all 20

Comment: yeah, you're right, I forgot to remove it

Comment: check only lines i, collumn j and square for i,j and everything in one condition, there is no reason to check anything else while you generate number for i,j

Comment: You have a total mess on your hands. You pass two dimensions to your function, implying they can be different. What does non-square sudoku ever mean? Then you completely ignore both dimensions inside the inner loop body and write your code as if both dimensions are fixed at 4. What do you want exactly?

Comment: @Angen I'm not too sure how to do it. Any example? That means I only use one 'while', right?

Comment: As for a more efficient method,  assuming you want your array square, your arrangement is called a *Latin square*. You may want to search for efficient Latin square generation methods.

Comment: @n.m yeah, I know it's a mess, cause I'm not sure how to use loop i and j to make the formula. And yeah, it's fixed at 4 (4x4 square). I just want all numbers inside the array different than each other at column and row like a sudoku: https://i.imgur.com/t1Uv699.png

Comment: Do you also want numbers in small 2x2 squares to be different?

Comment: @n.m Yes, just like the picture

Comment: Then it isn't quite clear why you expect your method to work. You surely can create an unsolvable sudoku where all the filled squares abide by the rules yet there are empty squares that cannot be filled. If you encounter this situation you need to **backtrack** (google it) and start over.

Comment: It is also not clear why you check e.g. `sudoku[2][0] == sudoku[1][0]` if your current index is `[0][0]` and you are only going to change it at this iteration. Surely if `sudoku[2][0] == sudoku[1][0]`, then it will stay this way forever, no matter how many random numbers you generate for `sudoku[0][0]` (and there are only 4 different good numbers). "The code works" looks like an overly optimistic statement to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is helpful but I found a simple algorithm in another [thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56149/how-can-i-generate-sudoku-puzzles) to generate a complete sudoku puzzle. For more details, check this thread. This is my short implementation of this algorithm:

```
std::array <unsigned int, 9> seed = {8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 6, 4, 5, 1};

std::array <std::array <unsigned int, 9>, 9> generate(std::array
    <unsigned int, 9> seed)
{
    unsigned int seedOffset {0};
    std::array <std::array <unsigned int, 9>, 9> field;

    field.at(0) = seed;

    for(unsigned int fieldIndex {1}; fieldIndex < field.size(); ++fieldIndex)
    {
        seedOffset = (0 == (fieldIndex % 3)) ? 1 : 3;
        std::rotate(seed.begin(), seed.begin() + seedOffset, seed.end());
        field.at(fieldIndex) = seed;
    }

    return field;
}
```